# GridViewRow Cells returning empty strings in button Click Event fire-up inside Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am confused with this problem.

I have put a button in side the template field of a gridview and want to return the data from that specific GridView Row when that corresponding button is clicked.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Button ID="Button2" CssClass ="btnSkin" runat="server" Text="Answer" Width="117px" onclick="Button2_Click" />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In the button click event fireup, I want to read that data by creating a GridViewRow Element.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
     Label8.Text = gvr.Cells[1].Text;
     Label10.Text = gvr.Cells[2].Text;
     Label12.Text = gvr.Cells[3].Text;
}
```

Now the problem is, the GridViewRow Cells are returning empty strings.

What should I do?????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `<asp:TemplateFields>`, you actually need to find the text which is inside your controls such as `<asp:Label>` you used inside your `<ItemTemplate>`.

Cells won't have text, its the Controls inside the cells that have text.

So, If suppose , you have a  Label inside one of your `<ItemTemplate>` as:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CustomerID") %>'>
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Then access the Text of this Label control  using below code in your button Click event:[ assuming, 2nd Column contains the above `<ItemTemplate>`  defined ]

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
        String str = ((Label)gvr.Cells[1].FindControl("Label1")).Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the reason behind the empty strings error.

`Gridview.Cells[i].Text` will return the string value only when it is a `<asp:BoundField>`

If it is a `<asp:TemplateField>` and you have some ASP control inside the `<ItemTemplate>`, you must follow the `FindControl("<control_id>")` approach.

Here, basically we look for the control object in that particular `GridviewRow` Cell by its ID and cast it into the corresponding Control Type. Now, we can use that as we call any other asp control from code-behind.

```
String str = ((Label)gvr.Cells[1].FindControl("Label1")).Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using GridView.RowCommand Event and refer the following link for the same

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx

hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanx for you help. But this is not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm using a Button control in the Template field, while I think rowcommand is used only in case of Buttonfileds. I'll try to do the same thing with the way you pointed. Thanks again.

Comment: You can Row Command in template field too.I'm writing aspx and c# code for you to understand it.

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View More">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnViewmore"  
            CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Name") %>' CommandName="More" runat="server" Text="View More" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

//c# code
 protected void gridMembersList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
   {
        if (e.CommandName == "More")
        {
            //your code here
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you are binding the grid properly on Page Load.

```
  if(!IsPostBack)
{
  BindgridView();
}
```

Hope this helps..Give a try..